# Powerpoint VBA to insert images based on a file path contained in the slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I produce a lengthy powerpoint report each month. Each slide has a text box containing a file path pointing to different image file. Is there a simple piece of VBA which could reference those file paths, and replace them with the associated image? Any support gratefully received.

Comment: Don't ask for code. Do a bit of work yourself and if that's not enough then come here asking for help with your code. Nobody wants to do the entirety of your job for you.

Comment: No code necessary, just a point in the right direction. I'm just looking to understand whether it's possible to do this. If not, then I can set the report up a little differently.

Answer (score 0):

Just cut together code from:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/245c1ee3-0731-4ef5-b934-fea5291b3b7b/vba-how-do-i-pass-the-text-in-a-powerpoint-text-box-into-a-variable-in-excel?forum=isvvba
http://support.microsoft.com/KB/168649

I don't know how you are running it so I have not included it in a `sub` but you would still need to change which presentation to open and the correct slides and shapes. I would recommend having it in a `Module` and also passing parameters for `slideNo As Integer, shapeNo As Integer, fileName as String`.

```
Dim oPP As PowerPoint.Application
Dim oPPT As Presentation
Dim oShp As Shape
Dim sText As String

Set oPP = New PowerPoint.Application

Set oPPT = ActivePresentation
Set oPPT = oPP.Presentations.Open("c:\sample.ppt")

Set oShp = oPPT.Slides(1).Shapes(3)

sText = oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text

Dim oSlide As Slide
Dim oPicture As Shape

ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide 1

Set oSlide = ActiveWindow.Presentation.Slides(1)

Set oPicture = oSlide.Shapes.AddPicture(sText, _
   msoFalse, msoTrue, 1, 1, 1, 1)
oPicture.ScaleHeight 1, msoTrue
oPicture.ScaleWidth 1, msoTrue

With ActivePresentation.PageSetup
  oPicture.Left = (.SlideWidth \ 2) - (oPicture.Width \ 2)
  oPicture.Top = (.SlideHeight \ 2) - (oPicture.Height \ 2)
  oPicture.Select
End With
```